# OAuth2: authenticate with email instead of username

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I'm using OAuth2 with django-oauth-toolkit django-rest-framework.

I usually authenticate my users the following way, in order to get a token:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=new_user&password=new_user" -u "GZwzDjPM89BceT8a6ypKGMbXnE4jWSzsyqbM3dlK:" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

Is there a way to use the email instead of the username to authenticate my users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! it is possible by setting the email as `username` in User model.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
 email =  models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
 )
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

 USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

then email can now be used as `username` in the request.

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=test@test.com&password=new_user" -u "GZwzDjPM89BceT8a6ypKGMbXnE4jWSzsyqbM3dlK:" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to (or can't) create a custom User model, here's a simple solution: Just override the `rest_framework_social_oauth2.views.TokenView` like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import rest_framework_social_oauth2.views

class TokenView(rest_framework_social_oauth2.views.TokenView):
    def create_token_response(self, request):
        email = request.POST.pop('email', None)
        if email:
            username = get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email[0]).values_list('username', flat=True).last()
            request.POST['username'] = username
        return super(TokenView, self).create_token_response(request)
```

Then, in your `urls.conf` wire up this customized view to the `oauth/token` pattern, e.g.:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^oauth/token', my_auth.TokenView.as_view()),  # The customized TokenView
    url(r'^oauth/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls')),  # Original URLs
]
```

Comment: url should be `oauth/token/` to override default url of oauth2

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this question was never answered, but anyways, I hope it would be useful my answer for whoever encounter this problem too:

**The ugly but quick way:**

Send the email as username in your POST request, then find its true username and replace your POST request with this data instead; all this in your middleware:

```
class DisableCSRF(object):
    """Middleware for disabling CSRF in a specified app name.
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        """Preprocess the request.
        """

        if (resolve(request.path_info).app_name == "api") or (
                resolve(request.path_info).namespace == "oauth2_provider"):

            if resolve(request.path_info).namespace == "oauth2_provider":

                post_data = request.POST.copy()

                true_username = User.objects.get(
                    email=request.POST.get("username")
                ).username
                post_data["username"] = true_username
                request.POST = post_data

            setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
        else:
            pass  # check CSRF token validation
```

**The elegant and good practice way:**

Create your own class to request auth tokens so you can receive the email as your username. You can even add more custom authentications like Facebook or Google logins. This is definitely the best way to do it but it takes some more time to develop, so its up to you if you have enough time to implement it.

Hope it's not too late for answering this.

Answer (score 0):

knaperek's answer did not work out for me.
Based on his code, I ended up with the following solution that worked great for my case:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from oauth2_provider.views.base import TokenView
from oauth2_provider.models import get_access_token_model
from oauth2_provider.signals import app_authorized
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class TokenView(TokenView):
    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters("password"))
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        email = request.POST.pop('email', None)
        request.POST['username'] = get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email[0]).values_list('username', flat=True).last()
        url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request)
        if status == 200:
            access_token = json.loads(body).get("access_token")
            if access_token is not None:
                token = get_access_token_model().objects.get(token=access_token)
                app_authorized.send(sender=self, request=request, token=token)
        response = HttpResponse(content=body, status=status)

        for k, v in headers.items():
            response[k] = v
        return response
```